# Load foreign model instances into queryset.values()

Tags: django, orm

I have queryset that groups and aggregates some data:

```
EmployeeAssessment.objects.all().annotate(month=TruncMonth('assessment_date')).values(
    'month', 'assessed_employee', 'subject'
).annotate(average_score=Sum('scores__score') / Count('scores__score', distinct=True))
```

And because of `.values()` I get assessed_employee and subject as IDs rather than model instances

I know that there are some similar questions here, but they're all talking about single relation, that can be reversed to get the needed data from related model.

My problem is that I need to get **two** nested objects: "assessed_employee" and "subject". Both of them are ForeignKeys

I use DRF serializer like this:

```
class EmployeeAverageScoreSerializer(Serializer):
    month = DateField()
    assessed_employee = EmployeeSerializer()  # <- ModelSerializer
    subject = AssessmentSubjectSerializer()  # <- ModelSerializer
    average_score = FloatField()
```

It is ok if I will have some subqueries or something, but I need a single queryset that still can be paginated.

How can I load models by ID after applying ".values" or maybe what other way can I use to get that data without losing model instances in resulting queryset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my case was that I needed to show some aggregated data along with nested models data in the response.

Solution is to use the `Subquery` to query the aggregated values.
Firstly I use `distinct()` to get the values that are equal for all aggregate groups, and then I use `Subquery` to enrich those rows with aggregated data:

```
average_score_subquery = (
    Employee.objects.all()
    # ... here is some filtering we need
    .annotate(month=TruncMonth('assessment_date'))
    .filter(  # First of all, filter a subquery by our row values
        assessed_employee=OuterRef('assessed_employee'),
        subject=OuterRef('subject'),
        month=OuterRef('month'),
    )  # Then use values() to group them by distinct values
    .values('assessed_employee', 'subject', 'month')
    .annotate(  # Finally, add aggregated data to the queryset
        average_score=Cast(Sum('scores__score'), output_field=FloatField())
        / Count('pk', distinct=True)
    )
    .values('average_score')  # Subquery must return no more than 1 column, so we use values() again to narrow the subquery to our aggregated column
)
return (
    Employee.objects.all()
    # ... here is some filtering, THE SAME FILTERING AS ABOVE
    .filter(assessed_employee=employee)
    .annotate(month=TruncMonth('assessment_date')) # I can't reuse annotation from subquery used to get aggregated data as subquery must return 1 column, so I do this again as I need it too
    .distinct('subject', 'assessed_employee', 'month')  # Distinct values
    .annotate(average_score=Subquery(average_score_subquery.values('average_score')[:1]))  # add the aggregated column from the subquery
    .order_by('-month')
)
```